# Graph isomorphic and subgraph isomorphic using R studio

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using R-studio to find the Graph isomorphic and subgraph isomorphic. As i'm new in R I could not find the explanation of the following results:

```
>graph.subisomorphic.vf2(g1, g2)
$iso
[1] TRUE

$map12
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 15  0 14  0  0  0  0  0 16 17

$map21
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 16 14 22 23
```

From the documentations, map12 is mapping g1 to g2 and map21 is mapping g2 to g1. But these numbers meaningless to me. What does the list of numbers mean? If I assumed that it refer to the elements, then the number 21. where does 23 comes from?

My second question, Does R shows which vertex map to which. For example A,B is vertices of G1 and C,D vertices of G2 . If G1 and G2 are isomorphic, is there any mention that returns for example A->C(A map to C), B->D(B map to D).

Thank you

Comment: Rather than mentioning the IDE you are using, you should instead provide `library` calls to load the packages you are using, and you should provide the output from `dput(g1)` and `dput(g2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The i-th element of `$map12` tells you which vertex in `g2` the i-th vertex of `g1` belongs in the subisomorphism mapping (and zero means that the vertex is not mapped at all). So, for example, element 14 in `$map12` is 15, which means that vertex 14 in `g1` belongs to vertex 15 in `g2`.

`$map21` is the inverse of this mapping: the i-th element of `$map21` tells you which vertex in `g1` the i-th vertex of `g2` belongs to. (Here you will not see any zeros). So, you can immediately see that element 15 in `$map21` is 14, meaning that vertex 15 in `g2` is mapped to vertex 14 in `g1` (which is what has already been said in `$map12` of course).